# Where is this Hockley Valley, in Ontario?

Tags: identify-this, ontario

I emailed [Mono Cliffs Provincial Park](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park/monocliffs) whether I could have taken this picture there. But they replied no, this definitely ISN'T their park. To them, this picture looks like Hockley Valley, but they are uncertain. Please geolocate this on Google Maps?

I took this pic, so I know the location, and want to go back. But I forgot the exact spot.

[image]

Comment: We are very picky in allowing location requests. Can you please add a lot more details on why you want to know the location and why you think it can be the suggested one?

Comment: Use Google street view, and try to find type of tree and hills. (Yeah, there is also a popular game about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am judging by the well manicured lawn, that this is Hockley Valley Resort?

https://www.google.com/maps/@43.9774973,-80.0490601,3a,75y,246.13h,87.75t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1siHPo8JDEZ0OYSY_PVH-WKQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?authuser=0&entry=ttu